# How to aim bullets at a player in Vavio

Tags: lua, modding

In [Vavio](https://peculiarcarrot.itch.io/vavio), how do you make an enemy aim at the player then shoot a bullet? Here's the code I tried:

`LevelSpawnData/spawnData-L0.json`

```
{
"spawns": [
    {
      "time": 3.2,
      "leave": 12.8,
      "pattern": "Test/aim.lua",
      "movement": "Test/move.lua",
      "model": "circle",
      "material": "red",
      "x": 0.5
    }
  ]
}
```

`Patterns/BulletSpawning/Test/aim.lua`

```
bullet = pattern.NewBullet()
bullet.speed = 3
bullet.angle = ??? -- Want to set this to angle towards player
pattern.SpawnBullet(bullet)
```